# Plot lines not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

Whenever I try to run this code the plot lines don't show up. Does anyone have any ideas as to why?[This is a picture of my code too for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWu0R.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p1 = 1*(10**-3)
p2 = list(range(1,101))
newlist = []
for i in range(1,100):
    db = 10*np.log10(p2[i]/p1)
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot (db, p2[i], 'c')
    plt.title('Log-Linear Plot')
    plt.ylabel('Power')
    plt.xlabel('db')
    plt.grid
    plt.show()
    plt.grid(True)

for i in range(1,100):
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.semilogy(db, p2[i], 'r')
    plt.title('Linear Plot')
    plt.ylabel('Power in Watts')
    plt.xlabel('Power in Decibels')
    plt.show()
    plt.grid(True)
```

Comment: Should plot.show be included within the loops?  The grid should also be added before the graph is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably what you're after.

You were using the loop to update the array, but also had `plot` and `show` in the loop, which would create many separate plots.  There's no need to call `plot` point by point, so that came out of the loop.

Also, though, using Numpy's vectorization, you don't even need to do the calculation in the loop, so I took that out as well, which left no loop at all.

[image]

```
p1 = 1*(10**-3)
p2 = np.arange(1,101)
newlist = []

db = 10*np.log10(p2/p1)
plt.plot (db, p2, 'c')
plt.title('Log-Linear Plot')
plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.xlabel('db')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


plt.figure(2)
plt.semilogy(db, p2, 'r')
plt.title('Linear Plot')
plt.ylabel('Power in Watts')
plt.xlabel('Power in Decibels')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```